# Why this Output is BarBarBar and not FooBarFoo?

Tags: php

I am starting to learn PHP and have a problem understanding this:

```
<?php

class Model {
    public $text = "Foo";
}

class Controller {
    public $model;
    public function __construct(Model $model) {
        $this->model = $model;
    }
}

class View {
    public $model;
    public function __construct(Model $model) {
        $this->model = $model;
    }   
}

$model = new Model();
$controller = new Controller($model);
$view = new View($model);

$controller->model->text = "Bar";

echo $model->text;
echo $controller->model->text;
echo $view->model->text;

?>
```

I just changed the valor of text of the object model property of the controller class. I think this has to do with some references.

Comment: Because they're all just pointers to the same instance of Model

Comment: OOP is not a good place to start learning a language.  They tried to do that to me at university by forcing me to learn Java.

Comment: Because you echo the current value of a property of the model instance, not the value of the property as it was when you assigned the model to an internal variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you affect your `$model` to the controller, you only pass a pointer to a `Model` instance. So in the end, you only have one `Model` instance. So when you change the value of `$controller->model->text`, you change the value of the text property of your only `Model` instance, which will output `Bar` each time, no matter you call it through the `$model` reference or the `$controller->model` one.

Comment: They're not passed by reference technically.. they are passed by memory pointer, read here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php

Comment: @RaggaMuffin-420 Its a thought trap really.  Variables pointing to objects and variables pointing to scalars work exactly the same way.  Its just confusing because unlike in C, you don't change the state of something like a string.

Comment: @Flosculus Yeah, i know what you were trying to get at. but if you're trying to teach some one something about the language, teach them right.. you know..  a reference in PHP is different to how objects are stored in memory.

Comment: @RaggaMuffin-420 Right, fixed. I won't write a whole page on the difference between passing a copy of a pointer and passing a reference to it, cause I feel that would be even more confusing for the OP at this point (and your link does it well enough :) )